# Quillen adjunction and properness

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, model-categories

Suppose we have a Quillen adjunction between model categories 
$$L:A\leftrightarrow B: R $$
such that $A$ is left proper model category. Let $a\leftarrow b\rightarrow c $ be a diagram in $A$ such that $b\rightarrow c$ is a cofibration then (as far as I understand) $a\sqcup_b c$ is a homotopy pushout in $A$.

**question**

Is it true that $L(a)\sqcup_{L(b)} L(c)$ is a homotopy pushout in $B$ ?

Comment: Have you seen: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138946/two-homotopy-colimit-questions

Comment: See also Rezk's comment here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82813/does-the-right-adjoint-of-a-quillen-equivalence-preserve-homotopy-colimits . This seems to show that the answer to your question is "no", since Ch(R) is certainly left proper.

Comment: @DavidWhite I don't see how do you "conclude" that the answer is "no"  following your links.

Comment: I'm not claiming it's trivial, but I don't have any free time this week to work it out. Try to compute a homotopy pushout in Ch(R) and then apply $S\otimes_R -$ where $R\to S$ is a non-flat morphism. You should run into trouble, not knowing the resulting thing is exact. At least, that's what I got from Rezk's comment. I was thinking an easier counterexample might be to use $L = Id$ on a category where the trivial cofibrations are isomorphisms and the fibrations are all maps, but I just don't have any time to think about it at this point.

Comment: @DavidWhite My comment in that question was about a slightly different issue (which has to do with the use of the phrase "homotopy colimit diagram"; it is possible to have a "homotopy pushout square" in which none of the sides are cofibrations).

Comment: Also, be careful: the conclusion can be true (I think it's true if $B$ is also left proper), but the values of the functor $L$ on $a,b,c$ or the push out might not coincide with the values of the *derived* functor of $L$ on these object.